# Issue with a real time chart with mysql connection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, performance

I want to show a real time chart but I haven´t had good results,  I´m using canvasjs library and I use a mysql connection to do this but after some minutes receiving information, I have the next problem: 
       [[image: Failed to connect the database:[1]]

The data that I want to show comes from a medical device and this send around 1000 records per second , I can establish connection to receive the information but some minutes later this connection is lost, also I have a error in PHPMyadmin when i try to access:

[image]

If you can see is the same problem that I show you previously.
Here is the query that I use to obtain the information from the database:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
 echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
$data_points = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM values where id=10"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$point = array("value1" => $row['valueX'], "value2" =>$row2['ValueY']);
    array_push($data_points, $point);
}
echo json_encode($data_points);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If you have one suggestion or comment, please let me know.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Is that PHP script being executed 1000 times per second?  What web server are you using?  How many clients is it set for?  How many connections is MySQL set for?  How many is it using?  Is there "connection pooling" anywhere?

Comment: Hi Rick, the PHP script is executed 100 times per second.  I´m using a IIS 7.5 server and I only use one client. And I´ll be grateful if you can tell me an example of connecting pooling.

Answer (score 0):

100 per second is probably manageable without special actions.

Set up the browser to allow, say, 20 "clients".

Set up MySQL:

```
max_connections = 151 -- as it probably currently is
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1  -- if using SSDs, else 2
```

Then there will probably be no problem gathering data at 100 web requests per second, leading to 100 MySQL `INSERTs` per second.

"1000" would probably have issues.

Meanwhile, you can fetch thousands of rows (in a single `SELECT`) to produce your realtime chart.  But don't do that 100 times per second.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I don´t have more the phpmyadmin problem.